# Share wireless card with Arch Linux on VirtualBox

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm developing a software that needs to access the list of wifi networks in **Arch Linux**. This is easy, just run `iwlist scanning`.

The problem is: I'm running **VirtualBox** on **Mac OS X** and when I run this command I got the following return:

```
enp0s3     Interface doesn't support scanning.
lo         Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

So, how can I share my wireless card to use it on virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant access your WiFi adapter card from Virtualbox. You can only use some option like Bridge, NAT, etc.